# What is $index in facets count in algolia?

Tags: algolia

I have searched for $index in many sites but none of them define how to get value of this variable.For now i have to use Model for this like below:

Can someone please help me to solve this issue how to get $index in algolia facets count like below ?

```
$index->searchForFacetValues("age", ['filters' => 'age']);
```

I have already tried this many time but cant get the coreect result

```
$results = User::search($request->get('search'))->with(['filters' => 'age:23',]);
```

Want to get $index

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [this snippet from the docs](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php#initialize-the-client):

```php
// composer autoload
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// if you are not using composer
// require_once 'path/to/algolia/folder/autoload.php';

$client = Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\SearchClient::create(
  'YourApplicationID',
  'YourAdminAPIKey'
);

$index = $client->initIndex('your_index_name');
```

You get `$index` by calling `initIndex` on your Algolia API client instance.

If that's not what you're looking for, you probably need to rephrase your question :)